# Select records with timestamp

Tags: java, oracle

I select ts from database: ts = `Select ts from ...`  so now I have oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP in my variable. Now I need to select  all record with this timestam:

```
select * from ... where time = ts
```

How I can to this ?

Comment: Why can't this be done in single SQL Statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `PreparedStatement` ([Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)):

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("select * from ... where time = ?");
pstmt.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery;
```

Comment: sory but this int working: I got this exception : WARNING: Failed to execute: Select *  From TABLE Where  ts = 'oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP@88e201'  because: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: that is because you need `java.sql.Timestamp`, not `oracle.sql.Timestamp`